# Rails Fixtures took id of itself for relation id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a Ruby on Rails (4.1.14) project and had a fixture issue. What happened was since it didn't find a group fixture with a key of one or itself, it used one in the current file is this suppose to happen or is this a bug?

These are my user fixtures

```
one:
 username: rebelweb
 group: one
```

These are my group fixtures

```
admin:
 description: Administrator
```

My User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, class_name: Group, foreign_key: :group_id
end
```

Comment: I don't use fixtures but from what I remember shouldn't the group in user fixtures either user use an explicit id, or a label?  I.e `group: admin`, I assume fixtures is trying to find a label with a name of `one`, and the only one it finds is in your user fixtures, so it uses that id

Comment: This was just example , management get weird when we release our real data structures.

Comment: Well you're not really going to get any help when you won't post anything that causes the error.  Can you make a simple setup that reproduces it?

Comment: i fixed my issue. I just came across a weird fixtures issue where the relating model did have a fixture with the key used :one in above, so the fixture used its own id, so if the user had id 16 in the example above it would assign an group_id of 16, since there is no group fixture with a key of one